# How to set chart value label orientation with aChartEngine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using `AChartEngine` to create a simple bar chart in my Android App. I would like to know how to set the orientation (to vertical) of the labels which appear at the top of each bar (chart **value** labels). In  the tutorials I have read there is a `setChartvalueAngle` method on the `SimpleSeriesRenderer` class but this method does not seem to exist (compile-time error + not in Javadocs). Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Use api 
renderer.setXLabelsAngle(90);

Answer (score 0):

here you can create the labels as of your own choice..for example..

```
        XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Income");
        // Creating an  XYSeries for Expense
        XYSeries expenseSeries = new XYSeries("Expense");
        // Adding data to Income and Expense Series
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            incomeSeries.add(i,income[i]);
            expenseSeries.add(i,expense[i]);
        }

        // Creating a dataset to hold each series
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        // Adding Income Series to the dataset
        dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
        // Adding Expense Series to dataset
        dataset.addSeries(expenseSeries);

        // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
        XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(130, 130, 230));
        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
        XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        expenseRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(220, 80, 80));
        expenseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        expenseRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        expenseRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Income vs Expense Chart");
        multiRenderer.setXTitle("Year 2012");
        multiRenderer.setYTitle("Amount in Dollars");
        multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        for(int i=0; i< x.length;i++){
            multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);
        }

        // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
        // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
        // should be same
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);

        // Creating an intent to plot bar chart using dataset and multipleRenderer
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

        // Start Activity
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

try this it may help you..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this did not work for me - my code is similar to your answer, except I used `SimpleSeriesRender`, which `XYSeriesRenderer` inherits from anyway. I don't see any methods to change the orientation of the chart **value** labels